# iText: create Phrase from HTML

Tags: java, c#, html, itext

Is there a way to create a Phrase object from HTML in iText?

I am using iText# 7, but Java examples and iText 5 examples are still welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the most straightforward way of creating a PDF from HTML with iText7 (and pfdHTML)

```
// IO
File htmlSource = new File("input.html");
File pdfDest = new File("output.pdf");

// pdfHTML specific code
ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(new FileInputStream(htmlSource), new FileOutputStream(pdfDest), converterProperties);
```

You can convert HTML to `List<IElement>`, by using another static method of `HtmlConverter`

```
List<IElement> elements = HtmlConverter.convertToElements(new FileInputStream(src), properties);
```

Check out the resources at the iText website:

- https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-converting-html-pdf
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zlTdttU_XyU&feature=youtu.be